# React Proptype for array and its properties

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have an array of "this.props.invoiceList" and I did some functionality based on this array as "filter, map and length"

I'm getting following lint errors:

```
error  'invoiceList' is missing in props validation         react/prop-types
error  'invoiceList.filter' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
error  'invoiceList.map' is missing in props validation     react/prop-types
error  'invoiceList.length' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
```

I need a help to fix it, I tried with the following ways but Im not get the proper solution

1. invoiceList: PropTypes.array,
2. invoiceList: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.length)
3. withShape(PropTypes.array, { length: PropTypes.number })

Comment: Can you show the full function?

Comment: check this: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md

Answer (score 4):

You need to set validations for each prop in your component.

You can do this as follows:

```
import {PropTypes} from 'prop-types';
...
*YourComponentName*.propTypes = {
    invoiceList: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}
```

If it's an array of objects and you want to validate further, you could do:

```
    invoiceList: PropTypes.arrayOf(
       PropTypes.shape({
           name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
           description: PropTypes.string.isRequired
       })
   ).isRequired
```

This should resolve the linting errors.

You can learn more about PropTypes here;

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html